# DevExtreme DataGrid react-testing-library

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library, devextreme

Cannot test datagrid component

Here is example.
https://codesandbox.io/s/g921o?file=/src/components/Home.js

Please check test console. screen.debug() doesn't return dom with dataSource of data grid.
How to test data grid with simple array or with CustomStore.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this way helped, but then there is a problem of how to get updated number of rows if some action happened...

```
it("We are doing test1", async () => {
    render(<Home />);
    const rows =  await screen.findAllByText(/Test\d/);
    console.log(rows);
});
```

[HERE](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t1034029/datagrid-jest-enzyme-react-tests) they answer why the regular way doesn't work for their components...

Comment: They now have official docs how to test with React Testing Library... :)
Check here: https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/React_Components/Components_Testing/#Unit_Testing